# Is there any better way to handle this function with multiple if statements doing almost the same?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, typescript

I have this function:

```
private addAdditionalResults(resultsToAdd: any) {
    if(!isNaN(resultsToAdd.xx) && this.x.length > 0)
        this.x.unshift(resultsToAdd.xx);
    if(!isNaN(resultsToAdd.yy) && this.y.length > 0)
        this.y.unshift(resultsToAdd.yy);
    if(!isNaN(resultsToAdd.zz) && this.z.length > 0)
        this.z.unshift(resultsToAdd.zz);
 }
```

x,y,z are arrays of numbers. resultsToAdd is an object with variables xx,yy,zz that can be something different than NaN. Is there anyway to make this code more beautiful? These if statements are doing almost the same.

Comment: If your arrays `x`, `y` and `z` are independent of your values `resultsToAdd.`/`xx`/`yy`/`zz`, no, there is no way to iterate over them. You still could create a function that makes the `if` statement + `unshift`, but you'd have to call it 3 times as well

Comment: does resultsToAdd have a specific interface or is it really any?

Comment: This looks good to me, would have no problems with a pull request of this kind.

Comment: {  xx: xxOff, yy: yyOff,  zz: zzOff, }; another function just fill this object with number, if it exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create variables with an array inside the function and then iterate over them. But this will affect your program response because of the loop.

```
results = array(resultsToAdd.xx, resultsToAdd.yy, resultsToAdd.zz);
numbers = array(this.x, this.y, this.z);

for(i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    if(!isNaN(results[i]) && numbers[i] > 0)
        numbers[i].unshift(results[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you and @joshua-j-wilborn, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the keys in advance and they follow a pattern, you could shorten it in the following way:

```
var variables = ['x','y','z'];
var that = this;
for (var key in variables) {
    if (!isNaN(resultsToAdd[key + key]) && that[key].length > 0) {
         that[key].unshift(resultsToAdd[key + key])
    }
}
```